# disabling full screen option on vimeo on ipad

Tags: ipad, vimeo

I've gone through the videos and disabled the "Full Screen" option in the embed section on vimeo, but the full screen option still appears when displaying the video in the iPad app. Any ideas of the problem? 
Thanks

Comment: When you say "on vimeo", do you mean when you use the Vimeo HTML embed code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be removed:

http://vimeo.com/forums/topic:52142